# Using OpenVino pre-trained models with AWS Sagemaker

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker, openvino

I'm looking to deploy a pre-trained model for real-time pedestrian and/or vehicle detection using the AWS Sagemaker workflow, I particularly want to use Sagemaker Neo to compile the model and deploy it on the edge.  I want to use one of OpenVino's prebuilt models from their model zoo, but when I download the model it is already in their Intermediate Representation (IR) format for their own optimizer.

1. Is there a way to get an OpenVino pre-trained model not in IR format so that I can use it in sagemaker?  Or any possible way to containerize the OpenVino model for use in sagemaker?
2. If not, are there any free pre-trained models (using any of the popular frameworks like pytorch, tensorflow, ONXX, etc.) that I can use for vehicle detection from a traffic camera POV?  AWS Marketplace does not seem to have much to offer in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to the query as below:

1. No.Only in Intermediate Representation (IR) format.
2. There are a few OpenVINO pre-trained models available for vehicle detection.Check out the list of Object Detection Models that are relevant for vehicle detection on these Github pages.
   https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/models/intel/index.md
   https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/models/public/index.md